# LeetCode 410: Split Array Largest Sum

Tags: c++, beginner, algorithm, programming-challenge, c++17

I'm posting my code for a LeetCode problem copied here. If you would like to review, please do so. Thank you for your time!

#### Problem

> Given an array which consists of non-negative integers and an integer
> `m`, you can split the array into `m` non-empty continuous subarrays.
> Write an algorithm to minimize the largest sum among these `m`
> subarrays.
>
> #### Note:
>
> If `n` is the length of array, assume the following constraints are
> satisfied:
>
> $$
>   1 \le n \le 1000 \\
>   1 \le m \le \min(50, n) 
>   $$
>
> #### Example:
>
> Input: nums = [7,2,5,10,8] m = 2
>
> Output: 18
>
> Explanation: There are four ways to split nums into two subarrays. The
> best way is to split it into [7,2,5] and [10,8], where the largest sum
> among the two subarrays is only 18.

#### Code

```
#include <vector>


class Solution {
public: 
    static int splitArray(const std::vector<int> &nums, const int m) {
        size_t lo = 0;
        size_t hi = 0;

        for (int num : nums) {
            lo = std::max(lo, (size_t) num);
            hi += num;
        }

        while (lo < hi) {
            size_t mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
            if (partitioning_is_valid(nums, m - 1, mid)) {
                hi = mid;
            } else {
                lo = mid + 1;
            }
        }

        return lo;
    }

private:
    static bool partitioning_is_valid(const std::vector<int> &nums, int partitions, size_t partition_max_sum) {
        size_t accumulate_curr_partition = 0;
        for (int num : nums) {
            if (num > partition_max_sum) {
                return false;
            } else if (accumulate_curr_partition + num <= partition_max_sum) {
                accumulate_curr_partition += num;
            } else {
                partitions--;
                accumulate_curr_partition = num;

                if (partitions < 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

};
```

#### Reference

LeetCode has a template for answering questions. There is usually a class named `Solution` with one or more `public` functions which we are not allowed to rename. For this question, the template is:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int splitArray(vector<int>& nums, int m) {
        
    }
};
```

- [Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/split-array-largest-sum/)
- [Solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/split-array-largest-sum/solution/)
- [Discuss](https://leetcode.com/problems/split-array-largest-sum/discuss/)

Comment: You can change the following lines in your source-code: `lo = *std ::max_element(nums.begin(), nums.end())` and `hi = std :: accumulate(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 0)` and remove the `for` loop. Do make sure that to use this functions you need to include `<algorithm>` header file which by default is included in the Leet-Code default template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Function signatures

You've made the best out of a slightly silly situation. I think your function signatures, while abiding to the template, have improved since the last post of yours that I reviewed.

I'm not sure whether this will break LeetCode compatibility, but if you want to enforce that no one can instantiate this class, try making a private default constructor.

### Mean

A simpler way to express the arithmetic mean than

```
        size_t mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
```

is

```
        size_t mid = (hi + lo) / 2;
```

Comment: _1 ≤ n ≤ 1000_ so overflow is not an issue here unless you're using an 8-bit type, which you are not.

Comment: On second read they leave the range of the actual array entries ambiguous? So maybe it's safe to keep the overflow-conscious version.